# exp_cartthrob_cart is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Tags: cartthrob, database, mysql

On two separate websites in the past few months (one with EE 2.8.1 and CartThrob 2.6, and another with EE 2.5.5 and CartThrob 2.3.6), we've had an EE website break due to a corrupted CartThrob table (showing a white screen to users). This is the error message we had:

```
Error Number: 145
Table './databasename/exp_cartthrob_cart' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
SELECT `cart` FROM (`exp_cartthrob_cart`) WHERE `id` = '0' LIMIT 1
Filename: third_party/cartthrob/models/cart_model.php
Line Number: 28
```

To fix the issue, we simply repaired the exp_cartthrob_cart table in phpMyAdmin. For info, this is what phpMyAdmin said about the table before we repaired it:

[image]

And in the SQL dump we did before the repair, it only exported the following for this table:

```
-- Table structure for table `exp_cartthrob_cart`
--
-- in use(#145 - Table './databasename/exp_cartthrob_cart' is marked as crashed and should be repaired)
-- Error reading data: (#145 - Table './databasename/exp_cartthrob_cart' is marked as crashed and should be repaired)
```

Although the fix was simple, I'm concerned in case the issue happens again, given it's already happened twice now on two different sites (both on different web servers too).

Does anyone have any idea why this might have happened and how we can stop it from happening again please? Thanks.

Comment: I had the exact same problem yesterday. Once again, table repair fixed the problem. Did you hear anything further in the end? Cartthrob 2.4
EE 2.7.2 I use Matrix to modify prices. Recently upgraded Matrix to 2.6.1

Comment: I never heard anything back from CartThrob about this, even after tweeting them. Might be worth you posting on Twitter using the #eecms hash tag and see if you have any more luck than I did. It's not happened since for me.